# ClassNotFoundException while configuring JMS with TIBCO

Tags: jms, tibco, tibco-ems, ready-api

While configuring JMS for tibco i am getting this error :

```
Could not establish JMS connection: javax.naming.NoInitialContextException: 
Cannot instantiate class:"Initial Context Factory class name".[Root exception 
is java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:"Initial Context Factory class name"]
```

Class not found Exception is coming.
What could be the possible error . Is this error possibly because of any missing Jar ? are the Tibco jars required ? tibjms.jar

```
Initial Context class : com.tibco.tibjms.naming.TibjmsInitialContextFactory
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to include the following libraries in `classpath`.

- tibjms.jar
- tibcrypt.jar
- jms-2.0.jar

Comment: @shiv, Appreciate if you can accept it as [answered](https://stackoverflow.com/tour)

Comment: Maybe change tibcript.jar to tibcrypt.jar first ... ;-)

Answer (score 0):

1. jms-2.0.jar
2. tibjms.jar
3. tibcrypt.jar

Copy 3 above files from C:<TIBCO-HOME>\ems<VERSION>\lib to C:<TIBCO-HOME>\bw<VERSION>\lib

Then, restart tibco.

Good luck!